# Improving performance of DotNetZip memory extraction

Tags: c#, wpf

Since converting my code to read resources from an archive, i have noticed a small drop in the performance of my application. How would i improve the following code to help to boost the performance back to as it was when using a flat file system or as close to as possible.

```
class Resource
{
    private static readonly string ResourcePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "resources.pak";
    private const string ResourcePassword = "0ORzjHcFxV0QXTuOizu0";

    private static ZipFile Read(string filepath, string password = null)
    {
        var file = ZipFile.Read(filepath);
        file.Password = password;
        return file;
    }

    internal static List<string> GetFiles(string haystack, string needle = "*")
    {
        var resource = Read(ResourcePath, ResourcePassword).SelectEntries(needle, haystack);
        return resource.Select(filepath => filepath.ToString().Replace("ZipEntry::", "")).ToList();
    }

    internal static MemoryStream ReadFile(string filepath)
    {
        var file = Read(ResourcePath, ResourcePassword);
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        file[filepath].Extract(stream);
        return stream;
    }

    internal static ImageSource StreamImage(string filepath)
    {
        var getFile = Resource.ReadFile(filepath);
        var imageSource = new BitmapImage();
        imageSource.BeginInit();
        imageSource.StreamSource = getFile;
        imageSource.EndInit();
        return imageSource;
    }

    internal static int[] ImageSize(string filepath)
    {
        int[] sizeValues = {0, 0};
        var readImage = Resource.ReadFile(filepath);
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.StreamSource = readImage;
        image.EndInit();
        sizeValues[0] = image.PixelWidth;
        sizeValues[1] = image.PixelHeight;
        return sizeValues;
    }

}
```

Please note that i have removed the error checking to keep the code short and to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by a drop in performance?  I imagine you mean responsiveness?  This would probably be because you are unpacking these resources on the main thread.  Move this work to a background thread.

Here is an example for .Net 4.5, using async / await.  (untested)

```
class Resource
{
    private static readonly string ResourcePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "resources.pak";
    private const string ResourcePassword = "0ORzjHcFxV0QXTuOizu0";

    private static ZipFile Read(string filepath, string password = null)
    {
        var file = ZipFile.Read(filepath);
        file.Password = password;
        return file;
    }

    internal static List<string> GetFiles(string haystack, string needle = "*")
    {
        var resource = Read(ResourcePath, ResourcePassword).SelectEntries(needle, haystack);
        return resource.Select(filepath => filepath.ToString().Replace("ZipEntry::", "")).ToList();
    }

    internal static Task<MemoryStream> ReadFile(string filepath)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var file = Read(ResourcePath, ResourcePassword);
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                file[filepath].Extract(stream);
                return stream;
            });
    }

    internal async static Task<ImageSource> StreamImage(string filepath)
    {
        var imageSource = new BitmapImage();
        imageSource.BeginInit();
        imageSource.StreamSource = await ReadFile(filepath);
        imageSource.EndInit();
        return imageSource;
    }

    internal async static Task<int[]> ImageSize(string filepath)
    {
        int[] sizeValues = { 0, 0 };
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.StreamSource = await ReadFile(filepath);
        image.EndInit();
        sizeValues[0] = image.PixelWidth;
        sizeValues[1] = image.PixelHeight;
        return sizeValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: The performance drop comes in the form of a white screen for a second or two whilst it loads. I am using PNG images but there will be other formats in the resource file in the future.

Comment: Right, in that case you need to move the unpacking to a background thread.  The easiest way is to use BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Thanks, could you give me an example using my code as i have never used them before and am fairly new to C#?

Comment: Which version of .Net are you using?

Comment: OK I'll put an async/await sample in my answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21215/discussion-between-nblackburn-and-james-l)